# como restar un día al termino del mes en PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hola chicos me podrían ayudar, no tengo idea de como hacer que que al terminar el mes me reste un día con dos rangos de mes ejemplo:

mes1:
Fecha inicio: 2022-10-30

mes2:
Fecha fin: 2022-09-29

en la fecha inicio el mes tiene 31 días
y la fecha fin tiene 30 dias

espero de su ayuda soy nuevo :(

Comment: Bienvenido pues! Ya que eres nuevo, léete [ask] y [example] para aprender a realizar mejores preguntas que sean mejor aceptadas en la comunidad. En tu pregunta no pones código ni errores que tengas, y tampoco se entiende demasiado lo que pides, la verdad, y así nos va a costar entenderte y darte respuestas certeras.

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo el uso DateTime  la función [modify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php)

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2022-10-31');
$datetime->modify('-1 day');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Available in PHP 5.3

$datetime = new DateTime('2022-10-31');
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Available in PHP 5.4

echo (new DateTime('2022-10-31'))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Available in PHP 5.5

$start = new DateTimeImmutable('2022-10-31');
$datetime = $start->modify('-1 day');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: gracias por su ayuda eso es lo que buscaba !! excelente dia